Got error "img is not a function" in Next.js 14
I've got this error on Next.js version 14 (App router) with Flowbite UI library
TypeError: img is not a function

I've checked around on Stack Overflow and GitHub Issues, but no luck.
I need to properly using Flowbite on Next.js 14 App router.
For additional information here is my Tailwind config.
import flowbite from "flowbite-react/tailwind";
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
import plugin from "tailwindcss/plugin";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./containers/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./node_modules/flowbite-react/**/*.js",
    flowbite.content(),
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    flowbite.plugin(),
    plugin(function ({ addBase, addComponents, addUtilities }) {
      addBase({});
      addComponents({});
      addUtilities({
        ".common-transition": {
          transition: "0.3s ease-in-out all",
        },
        ".divider-x": {
          "border-right": "1px solid #DEE3ED",
        },
      });
    }),
  ],
};
export default config;


Seems like it could be your usage of the Avatar component somewhere in your project. It seems the img prop passed to Avatar is not a string type, causing Avatar to try to call it as a function, but the error message suggests img is not a function either.
